# Deleting a comment from a locked post displays wrong message

Tags: bug

When I try to delete a comment from a locked post, the tooltip message informs me:

> Comments on locked posts are not eligible for voting

[image]

The message has nothing to do with the performed action. Change the message, if needed, to something like:

> Comments on locked posts can not be removed

Comment: Deleting a comment is technically a delete vote, so it is not wrong.

Comment: I think the bug needs to fixed so that one can delete a comment even if the post is locked. If I understand CC-BY-SA, it requires that anyone is able to disassociate from any posted content, and I don't think Stack will let users dissociate from a comment, as long as comments aren't considered "first class citizens" like posts are.

Comment: @Scratte I guess there's no need to be able to dissociate from a comment, since the comment can just be deleted. If the post is locked, just mod flag; they'll likely delete the comment without any fuss.

Comment: I know deletes are votes for posts, but is the same really true for comments too? Is it the same mechanism?

Comment: I'm being pedantic now, but I got curious so I dug into this lol. Based on SEDE, it looks like comment deletes *aren't* officially votes. Votes in the vote table have to be associated with a *Post*Id, which wouldn't allow a vote to be associated with a comment directly (which have their own Ids). I joined delete votes on comments and found matches, but the results didn't actually point to deleted comments.

Comment: When I try to **upvote** a comment in the same situation, I get the same message. I can however *flag* the comment. If any action on SO is a hidden "vote", the particular cases should be dissociated for the user messages, the user is not necessarily aware of the internal mechanism of SO user actions...

Comment: I just bumped into this. It seems daft that I can delete my own comments prior to a post locking and after the post automatically unlocks, but not during the lock period. Indeed I would like to remove posts during the lock period in order to reduce any tensions, and to give a disgruntled post author less to lash out against.